# yii2 multiple filter into search model

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, jquery-select2

i have a db structure like this:

```
Addresses
id primary key auto_increment
name
surname
email

categories
id primary key auto_increment
name

address_category
id primary key auto_increment
addr_id
cate_id
```

on the gridview, into categories filter column i have inserted a select2 extension with multiple set to true and on the addressesSearch model i have added this code:

```
->andFilterWhere(['address_category.cate_id'=>  $category]
```

it function but not like i want, yii make a IN query like cate_id IN (4,5,6) instead i need a query that find the address that are tagged with all the categories selected.

i hope to have explained well my problem

thanks

Comment: $query->andFilterWhere(['IN', 'address_category.cate_id',$category]);

Comment: this code you posted make the same i have already. i try to explain better, if i select the category client and invoice i want to search only address that are tagged with both client and invoice and not even client and legal or client and tech like is happening now. thanks

Comment: Try ->andFilterWhere(['address_category.cate_id'=>  $category])->andFilterWhere(['count(address_category.cate_id)'=>count($category)]);

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Answer (score 0):

select2 multiple returns comma separated values. split it first, maybe check for integer values

```
->andFilterWhere(['IN', 'address_category.cate_id', array_map('intval', explode(',', $category))]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i have find a solution, i don't know if is the best way but works.

```
                $query->select(['addresses.*, (select count(*) as categories from address_category where cate_id IN ('.implode(",",$category).') and addr_id=addresses.id) as categories']);
            $query->having(['categories' =>  count($category)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP's working solution may use a calculated field in the query, and that possibly ties-in with a solution that eventually worked for me, so this might just be an alternative approach. Note: I tried everything to parse/manipulate the attribute, but nothing worked.

So create a field in your model using a (getter), that simply replicates the attribute, so in a model which has a getter for a Country name in a country table with country_id as the attribute, something like:

```
public function getCountrylink()
{
return $this->country_id;
}
```

This (countryLink) is then used as the attribute in the view/index and as a simple replacement in the modelSearch filter:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['country_id' => $this->countryLink]);
```

N.B. You'll also need to add the calc field as a public variable and include as a safe entry in the rules in the modelSearch, as per standard instructions for establishing a calculated field (search for "Filter & Sort by calculated/related fields in GridView Yii 2.0").